# How can I get Stream from 3 dimensional array in Java 8?

Tags: arrays, java-8, java-stream

As I know to get Stream from 2 dimensional array but I want to know how I can get Stream from below 3 dimensional array?

```
 int[][][] data = {
                    {
                        {1, 2, 3},
                        {4, 5, 6},
                        {7, 8, 9}
                    },
                    {
                        {1, 2, 3},
                        {4, 5, 6},
                        {7, 8, 9}
                    }
                  };
```

Comment: A stream of what? If you know how you can do it for a 2D array, can't you extrapolate the solution to 3D?

Comment: I want to get IntStream. For 2D array solution is as per below:  

`IntStream is = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(row));`  

As a beginner in Java 8, I can't extrapolate the solution to 3D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can do it with a two-dimensional array then doing it for `N` dimensional array is not that difficult.

The solution can be done as follows:

```
IntStream result = Arrays.stream(data)
                         .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                         .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);
```

To better help understand what is going on above, you can split the method invocations as follows:

```
// the call to Arrays.stream yields a Stream<int[][]>
Stream<int[][]> result1 = Arrays.stream(data); 

// the call to flatMap yields a Stream<int[]>
Stream<int[]> result2 = result1.flatMap(Arrays::stream);

  // the call to flatMapToInt yields a IntStream
IntStream intStream = result2.flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream);
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, @Aominè

Comment: Hi, I have 2 question, could you please help? (Q1) Why have we used flatMapToInt instead of just flatMap? There was no requirement specified that we need stream of int  (Q2) I came up with a solution, which doesnt work but I cant understand why. I guess it might be related to Q1.  `Arrays.stream(data) .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x))  .flatMap(y -> Arrays.stream(y)) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 5):

You just need to call `flatMap` another time to change the stream from `int[][]` to stream of `int[]`.

```
IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(data)
                         .flatMap(twoDArray -> Arrays.stream(twoDArray))
                         .flatMapToInt(oneDArray -> Arrays.stream(oneDArray));
```

Comment: Thanks @YassinHajaj